# Make Wordpress go online

Tags: wordpress

I made a website with wordpress. The wordpress is installed with xampp. How to make it accessible for everyone? My link is http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/. When i try to access it with another pc. It failed. This site cant be reached.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is a [loop back address](http://www.tech-faq.com/127-0-0-1.html), thus cannot be routed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

127.0.0.1 is your localhost address, you won't be able to access that site from another computer. To make your site live, you need to buy a domain name (you can buy it from any hosting provider company) and a hosting package.

After buying the domain and hosting plan upload your site to the server.

Comment: is it possible to host my own domain?instead of buying it from other people. I want to use my pc as a server.

Comment: Adding to what @Akash stated, there is further [step by step help](http://www.endoflinemagazine.com/2013/11/xampp-how-to-move-from-local-to-webserver.html) available for moving from xampp to a host provider.

Comment: You would need to set up dynamic DNS mapping your domain name to your at home server.  There is some info [here](http://www.pcstats.com/articleview.cfm?articleid=1774&page=6)

Comment: @LeeAndroid yes you can do that. Here's a guide to help you set it up http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-Your-Computer-Into-A-Server-in-10-Minutes-fr/

But, you still need to buy a domain name.